# Clarify standards for rooms worth retaining in the chat FAQ

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, chat-faq

The chat FAQ says [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) that:

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

This could be understood in two ways.

- At least two users posted in the room. The number of all messages posted in the room is at least 15. (From my experience so far, it seems that this is how it works.)
- There are at least two users, such that each of them posted at least 15 messages.

I don't think that this could cause problems too often, but perhaps it might be better if the FAQ is unambiguous.

Comment: Of course it is possible that I am wrong about the ambiguity. (Especially considering that I am not a native English speaker.)

Comment: You may want to suggest an alternative wording where it's not as ambiguous, because I can't think of any :P

Comment: what about something like: *the room has more than 15 messages and at least two users have been active in the room*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be trivial to express unambiguously in Lojban.

Comment: @Jan Except only [the kind of people who learn Lojban](http://xkcd.com/191/) would understand it

Answer (score 3):

It isn't that unambiguous, 16 messages (more than 15) by at least 2 users means that there's a total of 16 messages in the room, which were spoken by at least 2 users. (So 15 messages from user1 and 1 message from user2 is considered worth retaining).